# Automatically selected the first record

Tags: c#

I created a C#.NET program to load the table to grid control. But, when I select a record in the grid control it automatically selects the first record. When I select the second time I can get the data in the correct row. I mentioned the code below.

Please help me to solve this issue;

```
private void dataGridView2_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
 textBox4.Text = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString();
 textBox3.Text = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString();
 textBox11.Text = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[3].Value.ToString();

 textBox1.Text = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[6].Value.ToString();

 //////////////////// stock code //////////////////////////////
 label14.Text = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();

 /////////////////////// category /////////////////////////////

 label12.Text = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[4].Value.ToString();

 //////////////////////////// purchasing price //////////////////////

 label10.Text = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[7].Value.ToString();

 ////////////////////////// actual quantity //////////////////////////////

 label11.Text = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You can extend your tags/description with the UI framework you are using (WinForms?)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set current cell selected explicitly

```
private void dataGridView2_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView grid = sender as DataGridView;
    grid.ClearSelection();
    grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected = true;

    //...rest of your code
}
```